# Unique ending lines for csv with bash

Tags: bash, csv

I would like to add a unique link to each line in a csv file in the following form

```
data1,name1,date1
data2,name2,date2
```

and afterward, it should look like

```
data1,name1,date1,somedomain.com/test-ZmQwZTdiNzIyZGExYTc1Njg1YjJjMWE2
data2,name2,date2,somedomain.com/test-ZTdmYjY4N2M5MjM0NzcxYjJjNGE0N2I5
```

whereby I was thinking to generate the unique strings with

```
date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32 ; echo
```

I found approaches for part of it but I am not sure how to put it together.

Comment: What does 'random' mean? Not very random if they are generated via the date earlier in the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` with the built-in `getline` command to call an external command and append the result to the end of each line.

Assuming your date is on the last field `$NF`

```
awk -F "," '{
    cmd = "date -d "$NF" +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32"
    cmd | getline hash
    print $0 FS hash
    close(cmd)
}' file.csv
```

**Input**

```
data1,name1,2017-11-01
data2,name2,2017-11-02
```

**Output**

```
data1,name1,2017-11-01,YTRiYWNmYmExMmM0NjJhYjAzNzU4ZGIx
data2,name2,2017-11-02,MTBjYjNlZTc5ZmNlMTU2NWFiY2Q2NmJk
```

Comment: Thank you @etopylight. How would I do it so that the output has the form somedomain.com/test-ZmQwZTdiNzIyZGExYTc1Njg1YjJjMWE2 ?

Comment: @user3550552 If you want to add a fix string before each hash, you can add it into the print command, for example `print $0 FS "somedomain.com/test-" hash` since the default behavior of print in `awk` is to concatenate all strings

Comment: @user3550552 Glad to help :)